# updating nulls based on column

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I got this very inconsistent record for example(just an example):

Manager | Associate | FTE | Revenue
Bob      | James |      Y |    500
Bob       | James   | NULL        | 100
Bob     | James    |   Y  |   200
Kelly   |  Rick       | N   | 200
Kelly   |  Rick |       N  |   500
Kelly   |  Rick        |  NULL   | 300

So the goal i wanted was to Sum up the revenue, but the problem is in the group by the nulls kinda split them apart.  So i want to write an update statement saying basically "well Looks like James and Bob are both FTE, so lets update that to Y and Kelly and rick are not so update that to no."

How can i fix this?  Using MSAccess and of course my table is a lot biger with a lot of different name combos.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the primary key columns, which makes it a bit harder. I've called it {id} below.

With the nulls, many SQL dialects have an "IfNull" function, but it seems MS-Access does not. You can get the same effect this way:

```
IIF(ISNULL(column),0,column)
```

You'd use that in a SELECT as so:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(Revenue),0,Revenue) FROM ...
```

For a one-off fix you could do this:

```
UPDATE {table} SET Revenue=0 WHERE Revenue = NULL;
```

Doing a join to get the FTE from another row is more complex, and I don't have access handy to see just what the limits and syntax are. The easy to understand way is a nested query:

```
UPDATE {table} a SET FTE = (SELECT max(FTE) FROM {table} b WHERE FTE IS NOT NULL AND a.{id} = b.{id})
```

The max() function works here because it ignores nulls, where some other functions return null if you pass a null in.

Comment: This is not really answering the question, since OP wants FTE to be either "Y" or "N" depending on the context, each time he encounters a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can "impute" the value by using an aggregation function.  The following query aggregates by `manager`/`associate` and takes the maximum value of `fte`.  This is then joined back to the original data to do the calculation:

```
select ma.fte, sum(Revenue)
from table as t inner join
     (select manager, associate, max(fte) as fte
      from table as t
      group by manager, associate
     ) as ma
     on t.manager = ma.manager and
        t.associate = ma.associate
group by ma.fte;
```

EDIT:

Immediately after posting this, I realized the `join` is not necessary.  Two aggregations are sufficient:

```
select ma.fte, sum(Revenue)
from (select manager, associate, max(fte) as fte, sum(Revenue) as Revenue
      from table as t
      group by manager, associate
     ) as ma
group by ma.fte;
```